# how to stringify the output from get-help <command name> command?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get just the syntax section that `get-help` outputs as a string, for example `get-help get-childItem` outputs:

```
NAME
    Get-ChildItem

SYNOPSIS
    Gets the items and child items in one or more specified locations.

SYNTAX
    Get-ChildItem [[-Filter] <System.String>] [-Attributes {Archive | Compressed | Device | Directory | Encrypted | Hidden | IntegrityStream | Normal | NoScrubData | NotContentIndexed | Offline | ReadOnly | ReparsePoint | SparseFile | System | Temporary}] [-Depth
    <System.UInt32>] [-Directory] [-Exclude <System.String[]>] [-File] [-FollowSymlink] [-Force] [-Hidden] [-Include <System.String[]>] -LiteralPath <System.String[]> [-Name] [-ReadOnly] [-Recurse] [-System] [<CommonParameters>]
....

DESCRIPTION
    The `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet gets the items in one or more specified locations. If the item is a container, it gets the items inside the container, known as child items. You can use the Recurse parameter to get items in all child containers and use the Depth parameter to
....
RELATED LINKS
    Online Version: https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1&WT.mc_id=ps-gethelp
....
```

I am interested in the `SYNTAX` section, I would like to take the output and print it with a simple function.
Many times, I don't wish to see all of the help output and want to just specifically see the command syntax, to get an idea for

- Positional parameters
- Mandatory parameter
- Optional parameters
- Parameter types
- Parameter sets

So I am thinking of writing a simple function called `syntax` and just do something like `syntax get-childItem` and it should only output:

```
Get-ChildItem [[-Filter] <System.String>] [-Attributes {Archive | Compressed | Device | Directory | Encrypted | Hidden | IntegrityStream | Normal | NoScrubData | NotContentIndexed | Offline | ReadOnly | ReparsePoint | SparseFile | System | Temporary}]...

Get-ChildItem [[-Path] <System.String[]>] [[-Filter] <System.String>] [-Attributes {Archive | Compressed | Device | Directory | Encrypted | Hidden | IntegrityStream | Normal | NoScrubData | NotContentIndexed | Offline | ReadOnly | ReparsePoint | SparseFile...
```

Getting this syntax section has proven to be a headache though, `get-help get-childitem|% syntax` will print just the syntax notation:

```
Get-ChildItem [[-Filter] <System.String>] [-Attributes {Archive | Compressed | Device | Directory | Encrypted | Hidden | IntegrityStream | Normal | NoScrubData | NotContentIndexed | Offline....
```

But one of my own functions will not. `get-help compile-autoHotkey|% syntax` prints:

```
syntaxItem
----------
{@{name=Compile-AutoHotkey; CommonParameters=True; parameter=System.Object[]}}
```

I wrestled with this issue and it just gets worse:

- `(get-help compile-autoHotkey|% syntax).tostring()` - Prints an empty line
- `get-help compile-autoHotkey|% syntax|write-host` prints  `@{syntaxItem=System.Object[]}`
- `"$(get-help compile-autoHotkey|% syntax)"` prints `@{syntaxItem=System.Object[]}`

Is there a reliable ways to get this information default commandlets and user defined functions?

PS: I know there are interactive ways to read the help and get syntax notation  such as PsReadline, I personally just want the syntax notation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax string from the `Get-Help` output is contained in the `.Synopsis` property, if you want to make a simple function it's as simple as:

```
function syntax {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Command
    )

    (Get-Help $Command).Synopsis
}

syntax Get-Item
```

Answer (score 2):

**Preface:**

- **[Santiago's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77856587/45375)** is **effective in *Windows PowerShell***, but **no longer in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, because it **relies on  a *bug* that has since been fixed**:

  - The **`.Synopsis` property should generally *not* include [syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax)**, and instead **should only report a command's *concise description***, as reported in the `SYNOPSIS` section of `Get-Help` output as well as of the *first paragraph following the heading* in the  online help topics such as [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)
  - The only situation in which it *does* make sense to have `.Synopsis` report the syntax diagrams is if a given command has *no help* associated with it at all (in which case no synopsis can be provided) - this is how it works in PowerShell (Core) 7+.

    - However, PowerShell (Core) 7+ has a *different* bug with respect to trying to make the `.syntax` and `.parameter` property values renders as expected for "help-less" commands - see [GitHub issue #21125](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21125) and the bottom section of this answer.

---

As a **robust, cross-edition alternative** to using [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help)'s output,  you can use
**`Get-Command -Syntax <command>`** to **get (just) the [syntax diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Command_Syntax)** for a given command, which also happens to *bypass* the aforementioned bugs.

- Your own attempt - which relies on [`Get-Help`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-help) output - would require compensating for these bugs - see the bottom section for an explanation and implementation.

Thus, you could define your `syntax` function as follows:

```bash
function syntax {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
    [string] $Command,
    # Optional parameter that provides context for discovery of dynamic parameters.
    [object[]] $ArgumentList 

  )
  process {
    $cmdInfo = Get-Command -Name $Command; if (-not $?) { return }
    # Windows PowerShell: Resolve an alias to its target command.
    # PowerShell (Core) does that automatically.
    if (-not $IsCoreCLR -and ($cmdInfo = $cmdInfo.ResolvedCommand)) {
      $Command = $cmdInfo.Name
    }
    Get-Command -Syntax $Command -ArgumentList $ArgumentList
  }
}
```

Note that the above automatically resolves *aliases* to their target commands in *Windows PowerShell* (which [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) does *by default*), so that you can call `syntax` as follows, for instance, relying on built-in alias `dir` getting resolved to `Get-ChildItem`:

```bash
syntax dir  # -> syntax diagrams for Get-ChildItem
```

- Pros:

  - This works even with PowerShell commands that *do not come with help*.

    - That is, it also works for PowerShell commands that come with  neither [*comment-based*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comment_Based_Help) nor [MAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Assistance_Markup_Language)-based help, provided via separate files.
  - Given that the information is directly derived from the actual commands via *reflection*, it is guaranteed to report the *actual* syntax, whereas it is technically possible for MAML-based information to diverge from the actual syntax.
- Potential con:

  - `Get-Command -Syntax` takes the current [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) context into account with respect to [*dynamic* parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#dynamic-parameters), whereas the information provided by `Get-Help` - *if* MAML-based - may choose to report dynamic parameters *across all providers* by default, as is the case with `(Get-Help Get-ChildItem).syntax`
  - To *situationally* compensate for that, the function above offers an optional  `-ArgumentList` parameter to which you can pass an argument that *implies a specific provider context*, analogous to [`Get-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-command)'s own `-ArgumentList` parameter, to which said argument is relayed.

    - While `-ArgumentList` only accepts *positional* arguments, the fact that *provider* cmdlets bind their first positional argument to the `-Path` parameter means that passing a single positional argument is sufficient to imply the provider context; e.g. to use the `syntax` function above to reflect dynamic parameters for the `Certificate` provider (e.g., `-Eku` and `-ExpiringDays`, invoke it as follows, which binds the `Cert:` drive specification positionally to `-ArgumentList`):

      ```bash
      syntax Get-ChildItem Cert:
      ```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `get-help get-childitem | % syntax`

The above:

- In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md): Malfunctions (doesn't render the syntax diagrams) for commands that *lack any help information*, which aren't just custom commands, but - depending on how PowerShell (Core) was installed - can include the built-in cmdlets.
- In *Windows PowerShell*: Malfunctions for *any* command.

What it comes down to is that `Get-Help` emits `[pscustomobject]` instances, including for the nested `.syntax` property, that rely on *[ETS](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) type names* to select suitable [output-formatting definitions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/format/formatting-file-overview) in order to render the value of the `.syntax` property

If the required ETS type name to select the desired formatting isn't reflected in the [intrinsic `pstypenames` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#type-information), the object contained in the `.syntax` property uses *default* formatting, which results in the - unhelpful - representation shown in your question.

**For the desired rendering of the `.syntax` property value to work consistently, its `.pstypenames` property value** must (also) include a **`MamlCommandHelpInfo#syntax` ETS type name**, whereas:

- in *Windows PowerShell* it *invariably* only contains `ExtendedCmdletHelpInfo#syntax` (only)
- in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* it contains `ExtendedCmdletHelpInfo#syntax` (only) for commands *without help*.

While this **problem** is unlikely to be fixed in *Windows PowerShell* (which will receive critical fixes only), it ***may* get fixed in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*** - see [GitHub issue #21125](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21125), which states that the **`.parameters` property is affected too**.

The **cross-edition implementation of a `syntax` function based on the `.syntax` property** would therefore have to look like this:

```bash
function syntax {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $Command
    )
    process {
        $syntaxInfo = (Get-Help $Command).syntax
        # Ensure presence of the relevant ETS type name.
        $syntaxInfo.pstypenames.Insert(0, 'MamlCommandHelpInfo#syntax')
        # Now the output should render as expected.
        $syntaxInfo
    }
}
```

Sample call:

```bash
# Declare a function without help, then ask for its syntax.
function Foo { param([int] $Bar) }; syntax Foo
```

Output (in both PowerShell editions):

```bash
foo [[-Bar] <int>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

As an aside:

- Note the - unexpected - inclusion of `[<CommonParameters>]` in the syntax diagram, given that the function is *not* an [advanced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) one and therefore doesn't support [common parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_CommonParameters).
  This problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #17312](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17312).

Comment: This is a very thorough and comprehensive overview of the state of things as they stand. Much appreciated!